# A Procedure to auto-increment a MYSQL Column based on the value of another Column

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a BOOLEAN column of 0 and 1 and I'm trying to add a column to the table to auto-increment from 1 whenever a new row is TRUE (1) or else return NULL. I'm not sure if it's a stored procedure or a stored function that I need here, or else just a simple CASE statement...Any tips?

I've tried messing around with stored procedures and stored functions and reviewing documentation but I'm not as familiar with general frameworks that can help me here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this BEFORE TRIGGER:

```
create table testtb (bl bool, autoincre int);
DELIMITER //
create trigger autoincre before  insert on testtb for each row begin
if new.bl = 1 then
    if (select max(autoincre) from testtb) is null then
    set new.autoincre=1;
    else
    set new.autoincre=(select max(autoincre) from testtb) + 1; 
    end if;
end if;
end //
```